# Find $S=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{1+n^2}$

Tags: calculus, summation

How do I find the sum:
$$S=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^n}{1+n^2}$$

I can't solve this can someone help me?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but it looks promising to try and find a function on $\mathbb T$ such that it's fourier transform is $a_k = \frac{(-1)^n}{1+n^2}$ with
$$f(x) = \sum_{k\in\mathbb Z} a_k e^{ikx}$$
To find candidates for such an $f$, look at plots of $f_N(x) := \sum_{k=-N}^N a_k e^{ikx}$ for increasing $N$ and see if you can guess the limit.

Comment: Hint: Think about the Fourier transform of $f(x)=e^{-|ax|}$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$$S=\sum_{n \ \text{even}} \dfrac{1}{1+n^2}-\sum_{n \ \text{odd}} \dfrac{1}{1+n^2}$$

Now, $$\displaystyle\sum_{n \ \text{even}} \dfrac{1}{1+n^2}=\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{1+(2n)^2}=\dfrac{1}{4}\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{1/4+n^2}$$

Also,
$$\begin{align}\sum_{n \ \text{odd}} \dfrac{1}{1+n^2}&=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{1+n^2}-\sum_{n \ \text{even}} \dfrac{1}{1+n^2}\\ &=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{1+n^2}-\dfrac{1}{4}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{1/4+n^2}\end{align}$$

Hence,
$$S=\dfrac{1}{2}\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{1/4+n^2}-\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{1+n^2} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$

Now, consider $f(x)=e^{-a|x|}, \ a>0$. Let $F(k)$ be the Fourier transform of $f$.
$$\begin{align} \therefore \ F(k)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-ikx}\mathrm{d}x\\ &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-a|x|}e^{-ikx}\mathrm{d}x\\ &=\dfrac{2a}{a^2+k^2}\end{align}$$

Now according to the Poisson summation formula,
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}f(n)=\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}F(2\pi m)$$

Therefore,
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-a|n|}=\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{2a}{a^2+(2\pi m)^2}$$

The LHS is just a geometric series. Summing it, we get
$$\begin{align}\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{2a}{a^2+(2\pi m)^2}&=\dfrac{1+e^{-a}}{1-e^{-a}}\\ \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(a/2\pi)^2+n^2}&=\dfrac{2\pi^2}{a}\dfrac{1+e^{-a}}{1-e^{-a}}\end{align}$$

Put $a=2\pi,\pi/2$ and substitute the results into $(1)$ to obtain
$$\therefore{S=\dfrac{2\pi e^{\pi}}{e^{2\pi}-1}}$$

Comment: Wolfram Alpha confirms your computations.

Comment: I believe your statement of the Poisson summation formula should say $F(2\pi m)$.

Comment: @JohnBarber Why do you say that?

Comment: @JohnBarber I see. No I meant to do that so OP knows where/how I got that

Comment: @YagnaPatel Your definition of the Fourier transform does not have a $2 \pi$ in the exponential term. For that definition of the FT, the Poisson Summation formula is: $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} f(n) = \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} F(2\pi m)$.

Comment: @JohnBarber: Good now?

Comment: @YagnaPatel Perfect! This is an outstanding answer.

Comment: @JohnBarber: Thank you

Answer (score 4):

We can use a result from complex analysis, specifically the residue theorem:

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} (-1)^n f(n) = -\pi \sum_k \operatorname*{Res}_{z=z_k} [f(z) \csc{\pi z}] $$

where the $z_k$ are the poles of $f$.  here $f(z) = 1/(z^2+1)$.  The poles are at $z_{\pm} = \pm i$.  Thus the sum is

$$-\pi \frac1{2 i} \frac1{\sin{i \pi}} - \pi \frac1{-2 i} \frac1{\sin{(-i \pi)}} = \frac{\pi}{\sinh{\pi}} $$

Comment: Nice, I didn't think of this way. So much shorter than mine

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Differentiate the natural logarithm of [Euler's infinite product expression for the sine function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem), and then employ the well-known relations between trigonometric and hyperbolic functions, in order to show that $~\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac1{a^2+n^2} ~=~ \frac\pi a~\coth(\pi a),~$ then, using Yagna Patel's relation $(1)$, evaluate *S*.